# Removed comment

Tags: discussion

May I receive some explanations about the reason of removing my comment from this question:
[Why do different smartphones with the same megapixel camera resolutions have different quality of image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/64284/why-different-smartphones-with-same-megapixel-camera-resolutions-have-different)

Moreover my comment (almost) answer (with few words) to the question

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, comments are meant to be used to ask for clarity or to suggest improvements to a question, not to answer. I will usually let such comments live for a while, but ultimately I will delete them, especially with viable and real answers in place.

See [Short answers as comments — please resist the urge](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge?rq=1) for additional details.

Comment: Joanne, my comment/answer was hours before answers you mention. And based on recommendation in mentioned by you discussion you should remove the question as requiring very broad answer. The subject is really huge.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - The comment was removed around the same time as two of the answers. As for the broadness of the question, perhaps, but I'm not sure that I agree with you and I'm not going to close on my own without being absolutely sure of it.

Comment: I see, but next time maybe we should require option to convert comment in answer. About broadness: 1. cmos technology, size. 2. different firmware, different interpretation of sensor data, different curves for convertion to eye "view", different internal filters as sharp, clarify, vibrance and so on. 3. DIfferent algorithms and levels for jpeg compression. If you check all those points you will see the good answer should be at least 5 screen pages long

Comment: @RomeoNinov - Moderators don't have that option. With respect to the question, you can flag for review queue. I will not close it with a moderator vote on its own, it's just not going to happen here.

Comment: Point taken, will flag it :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov My personal suggestion: when in doubt, either 1) post it as an answer, 2) don't post anything at all, or 3) phrase it in a way which makes it clear that you'll delete the comment later or expect it to be deleted.