# Where are our Help Center pages deficient or lacking?

Tags: discussion, help-center

*This question is inspired by the [Help spot deficiencies in our Help Center](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5017/9683) meta-question over at CodeReview.SE.*

Just about every community, organization, business, government, etc., is governed by two sets of rules: the written rules & regulations, and the "community rules" (or *the way things are done* but not codified).

We are no exception. Our Help Center documents what's on-topic, what's off-topic, and the like, but is lacking in some of our more frequent, shall we say, admonitions? My favorite example is [mattdm's](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm) excellent [anti-answer-in-comments manifesto](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/11924). When people answer in comments, you can expect a link back to that Meta question.

Another example is the set of "What's this effect?" –type questions.

But these are tripwire situations — the "rule book" didn't mention those scenarios, and posters usually find out about the violation only *after* they've broken the social rule.

Those are just a couple examples. I'm sure there are many more.

In the interest of possibly drafting better Help Center pages in the near future, **can we identify where our Help Center pages are deficient or lacking?**

*This is intended to be a brainstorming type of question, rather than detailed rewording of Help Center pages. I'm sure that will follow after the brainstorming... =)*